# Data not saving through model in yii2

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii, yii2

I am newbie to the Yii2 framework.

I am creating a custom form and saving its data to a table. 
I tried every solution that is here or on Google.

I am really getting frustrated.
Can anybody solve or give solution to this problem? If you need I can give you the code or access of the site as well.

Comment: An [mcve] would be great

Comment: I have a form for hgetting New Garage info from the Owner here is the code for the Controller

public function actionAdd()
    {
  $model = new AddGarageForm();
               if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save() && $model->validate()) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('alert', [
                'options' => ['class'=>'alert-success'],
                'body' => Yii::t('frontend', 'Your account has been successfully saved')
            ]);

            return $this->refresh();
        }

          return $this->render('add', ['model'=>$model]);
    }

Comment: here is the link for you to view

http://parking.ttabor.net/user/default/add

login 

abc@gmail.com

abc@123

Comment: @RahulGoswami You should edit your question with the code, instead of putting it in a comment. The comments won't format code correctly.

Comment: @NateBarbettini, Please check the url and let me know what is the problem

Comment: Any Solution ? i am not able to post the code here

Comment: any one with the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You cannot save the data into database using `form model`**

`form model` just introduced in yii to collect the user data. Later this data will be used and then discarded. It can not save the data into database.

To save the data, you should use `Active Records`

Comment: Can please tell me how to use it or any link ?

Comment: After extending Active Record , Now i am getting this error 

PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of frontend\modules\user\models\AddGarageForm::save() must be compatible with yii\db\ActiveRecordInterface::save($runValidation = true, $attributeNames = NULL)

Comment: Can anybody help me ?

Comment: @RahulGoswami - You might have used the same class by extending ActiveRecords. That is not the correct way. Generate Garage model and then Crud using GII and utilize the class.

Comment: How is this the selected answer? It didn't answer anything. In your custom form create a function to save the data by loading a new instance of the model. In your code where it calls validate, also call that custom function that handles the save. I can post an example in a bit. Just reply if you still need it.